# put 2 first letters in bold in c3.js - d3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, c3.js

in my code I'm getting a text next to the bars. I want the first 2 words of each text string ("my text") are bold.

[image]

I'm new to d3.js then I'm not sure how to create a label for "my text" with this property or something. Normally this would create

```
<Label> my text </ label> one
<Label> my text </ label> two
<Label> my text </ label> three
```

d3.js but I do not know how. I care only that "my text" be bold.

this is my code

```
    chartData=[
      ['data1',60,10,4,20],
      ['data2',30,30,5,20],
      ['data3',30,30,4,20]

    ]

    var chart = c3.generate({
        bindto: '#chart',
        size: {
            height: 500,
        },
        data: {
            columns: chartData,
            colors:{
              data1:'#00af50',
              data2:'#F7931E',
              data3: '#FF0000'
            },
            names:{
              data1:'namedata1',
              data2:'namedata2',
              data3:'namedata3'

            },

            type:'bar',

            labels: {
              //format: function (v, id, i, j) { return "Default Format"; },
              format: {

               data1: function (v, id, i, j) { 
                 return "my text one"; 
               },
                data2: function (v, id, i, j) { 

                 return "my text two"; 
               },
                data3: function (v, id, i, j) { 

                 return "my text three"; 
               },
              }
            }
        },


        tooltip: {
            show: false
        },    
        legend: {
            show: false
        },
        axis: {
            rotated: true,
            x: {
                type: 'category',
                categories: ['001', '002','003','004'],
                 tick: {

                 format: function (d) { 
                  return "" ; }
                }
            }        
        }    
    });

    var arrayOfPics = [
      "http://lorempixel.com/40/40/abstract",
      "http://lorempixel.com/40/40/animal",
      "http://lorempixel.com/40/40/business",
      "http://lorempixel.com/40/40/cats",
      "http://lorempixel.com/40/40/sports",
      "http://lorempixel.com/40/40/food"
    ];


    d3.selectAll('.c3-axis-x .tick')
      .each(function(d,i){
        // clear tick contents and replace with image
        var self = d3.select(this);
      //  self.selectAll("*").remove();
        self.append('image')
          .attr("xlink:href", arrayOfPics[i])
          .attr("x", -40)
          .attr("y", -20)
          .attr("width", 25)
          .attr("height", 25);
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qgxxvgxw/

Comment: I haven't worked with C3.js but how you would have to do it via html javascript etc is split the word up so instead of having on <p> tag containing the whole string, you would have two <p> tags. One containing the start of the string which would be in bold, the second holding the rest of the string, not in bold

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not much familiar with c3. But you can implement this by using d3.js.

```
updateLabels();
function updateLabels (){
    d3.selectAll('.c3-chart-texts .c3-text').each(function(){
       var text = d3.select(this).text();
       var openTSpan = '<tspan style="font-weight:bolder;">', closeTSpan = '</tspan>';
       text = text.split(' ');
       text.unshift(openTSpan)
       text.splice( 3, 0, closeTSpan );
       var newText = text.join(" ");
       this.innerHTML = newText;   
    });
}
```

**Update:**

To update the chart labels after zooming, try below code.

```
zoom: {
    enabled: true,
    onzoom: function (domain) {
      updateLabels();
    }
}
```

To update the chart labels after screen resize:

```
onresized: function(){
    updateLabels();
}
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hf4v1aso/1/

Comment: friend thank you very much. I hope you help me with this problem. If I maximized or minimized the screen, the bold disappears. why? and that I can do to fix it ?.

Comment: Hope you are using zoom functionality to maximize/minimize the charts. Updates in the answer may be helpful.

Comment: friend are very friendly and I am grateful for your time. but when I refer to maximize and minimize, I mean maximize and minimize the window. no zoom.

Comment: thank you very much friend. your help is invaluable but in the mobile version of this example with your help, the bold does not appear. word appears normal as it was before. I'm using ionic to generate an apk with this code. You know that can happen?

Comment: It is rare but finally decided as follows:                          d3.selectAll('.c3-chart-texts .c3-text').each(function(){
       
              var text = d3.select(this).text();
              text= text.split('|');
              console.log(text)
              d3.select(this).text(null);
              d3.select(this).append("tspan").
              style("font-weight","bold").text(text[0]+" | ");
              d3.select(this).append("tspan").text(text[1])
        });

Comment: Glad! at last you found a solution by yourselves.

Answer (score -3):

You could create a function to capitalize the first two words of your sentence and then call it by passing your actual sentence.

```js
function capitalize(str) {
  var indexOne = str.indexOf(' ');
  var indexTwo = str.indexOf(' ', indexOne + 1);
  var capStr = str.slice(0, indexTwo).toUpperCase();
  return capStr + str.slice(indexTwo);
}
```

```js
data1: function(v, id, i, j) {
  return capitalize("my text one");
}
```

Comment: he didn't say capitalize he said in bold